# how transistor amplify ac signal

Tags: transistors

Regards . 
My question is the following I do not understand how the transistor amplifies the ac  signal when the current through it does not change the direction  .

Comment: There are plenty of books and lectures about this subject. **Explain** why that's not good enough for you and you need a separate explanation. Hint: AC is superimposed on DC bias.

Comment: Of course there is a bunch of books but no one explains how the transistor changes the direction of the current as you know it is simply impossible because it works on the dc and as we all know the alternating current changing its direction if you need some further clarification unfortunately .

Comment: The current does not change direction, it only changes it's magnitude from low to high. Somewhere in between these extremes lies the average value, which is the DC component. Block this DC component with a capacitor, and you have pure AC.

Comment: *but no one explains how the transistor changes the direction of the current* which is impossible which you know because you write *it is simply impossible* so **obviously** the current does not change direction. So **obviously** something else is happening. Then why insist on getting the impossible explained?

Comment: This is one of those cases where "alternating current" is a bad name, it sort of implies the current is going back and forwards. "Modulating Current" is a better name, the current here is changing intensity and can be uni-directioanal. In transistor circuits things are typically biased to ensure the min and maximum current modulation values are always in the right direction. You can kind of think of it as two people throwing a ball back and forward on a moving train. To the two people the ball is changing direction, to the people beside the track, the ball never goes backwards.

Comment: you simply use two transistors, one in each polarity, like in a solid-state relay.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very general so I can only give you a general answer.  Assume you have a simple common emitter single NPN transistor amplifier.  The signal is applied to the base and the output is taken off the collector.  The transistor is biased by several resistors so that the collector current is positive, let's say at 10 ma. As the AC signal is applied to the base, the action of the transistor causes the current in the collector to vary in step around the DC bias value.  Let's say the current varies from 5 to 15 ma, that is a peak-to-peak value of 10 ma.  The current remains positive at all times in order for the transistor to remain in its linear region. But this current variation will generate an AC voltage across the collector resistor. This voltage can be AC coupled, through a capacitor, to produce an AC output voltage that is higher than the original input AC voltage. The main point is that the bias current allows the transistor collector current to remain positive while it is conducting an AC current in response to the input signal.